# ACCESS/ADO SQL non aggregated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ado

I have the following simple table.

```
ID Town Name Address Value
77000 Warsaw Mr.X MainStreet 1000
77000 Gdansk Mr.X ChurchStreet 2000
23232 Warsaw Mr.Y DonaldStreet 2000
23232 Warsaw Mr.Y DonaldStreet 1000
17071 Poznan Mr.Z 20Ave 5000
17071 Poznan Mr.Z 20Ave 7000
```

I want to sum values grouped by ID and Town
Ie.

```
Select [ID], [Town], Sum[Value]
From [MyTable]
Group by [ID, Town]
```

This is what I want, I need to aggregate, to sum for the same ID but in two towns two different sums.

NOW... I would like to have the remaining, non-aggregated columns, eg. with proper names [Name] street name [] and other data to be displayed with my result. And not take part in the aggreation and grouping by. Is it possible with one SQL query? 
If i simply include them, and there are small errors, upper,lower case in a name or a street name, these result in improper aggregation and multiple duplicates. I would like to show the columns showing names and addresses but exclude them from aggregating or grouping by.

I tried to study entries related to "non aggregated columns" but as SQL beginner I could not solve my simple example. Can you, my friends, help me find a solution for this problem, perhaps very simple for you.

I will appreciate all your help. I am sorry if this question is already answered somewhere else but I could not find a simple and clear answer yet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well what did you try?

Comment: You will still need to apply an aggregate to all non-grouped columns, e.g. `MIN(Address)`

Comment: Yes... This would be a great idea maybe to use some "dummy aggregation" on these columns. Is it somewhat a common solution to this problem? I have read and seen various proposals about generating first a table with results of the aggregation and then show them in another table... as a second step. But I could not reproduce it in this simple case. Can I use MIN(Address) MIN (Name) on all these text strings and get away with my problem? I will try this.

Comment: @StuartLC Thanks. This works.

Select [ID], [Town], Min[Name],Min[Street],Sum[Value]
From [MyTable]
Group by [ID, Town]

Comment: Yes, although its a fairly random-ish 'sample' of data from the group :)